# I there any relation between pinned object and memory fragmentation in .NET

Tags: c#, memory-management

> A pinned object is one that is not allowed to move. The garbage
> collector is normally compacting the memory in that it moves all
> objects to "one or more clusters". This is to create large chunks of
> free space.

Please consider this picture:
[image]

Why GC cannot defragment the G0?Is there any relation between pinned object and memory fragmentation?

Comment: G2 doesn't look very fragmented.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes I edit my post

Comment: _Is there any relation ..._ - yes of course there is. Compacting means moving and pinned means unmovable.